# Metadata on UIImage not using the camera roll - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Simply, I am trying to save/add GPS metadata into a UIImage which is then stored in a custom folder. I do not want this image to appear in the camera roll.

It appears that the "Photos Framework" won't help as this requires the image being added to the camera roll.
Other code I have seen online uses a lot of unmanaged code and so, this doesn't feel like a very "swift" way of doing things.

Does anyone have any resources that shows how to modify the metadata of a UIImage? or am I looking at this incorrectly.

Thanks